# Debian boots into initramfs, but /sbin/init is present

Tags: linux, debian, init

I was crossgrading Debian Stretch from i386 to amd64. The kernel is already 64-bit, so is dpkg/apt. I was going through the rest of the packages, and then I had to reboot the box.

Upon reboot, it goes into the recovery mode (initramfs). There are the following messages:

```
/scripts/local-premount/resume: line 34: /bin/resume: not found
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean
/init: line 267: run-init: not found
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
/init: line 267: run-init: not found
/init: line 267: run-init: not found
/init: line 267: run-init: not found
/init: line 267: run-init: not found
/init: line 272: run-init: not found
No init found. Try passing init= boot argument.
```

And then there's the busybox prompt.

The hard drive (/dev/sda1) is mounted into /root. fsck reports no issues. **`/sbin/init` is present there**, it's a symlink to `/lib/systemd/systemd`, which also exists (but remains 32-bit).

I can remount the hard drive as R/W and chroot into it. In that mode, I can get get some of the regular Debian stuff, like dpkg, to work. No network though, so no apt-get.

Please, what could be wrong with the boot environment? What else should I check? It's most likely something I did during the crossgrade process, not hardware or filesystem corruption.

EDIT: using another Debian box, found a tool called `run-init`. It's under `/usr/lib/klibc/bin`, comes in the klibc-tools package, and has to do with the initramfs operation. I'll try installing that. Now, if I could figure out a way to copy files to this box...

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure where did I go wrong. But after running

```
update-initramfs -u
```

in a chroot-to-sda1 environment, things were back to normal.

By the way, installing klibc-utils didn't help.

Also, I got the wired network to work in initamfs. After remount/chroot, the `ifup eth1` command stood up the network, and I could download packages again.